# php - mail() expects at least 3 parameters. But I already declare properly the variables

Tags: php, email

```
<?php
$targetEmail = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Sending e-mails from PHP is fun!';
$message = 'Do you agree?';

mail($targetEmail, $subject, $message);
echo mail(); //I use this to see the error
?>
```

I've already set that variable but when I echo it, it said `Warning: mail() expects at least 3 parameters, 0 given` And I'm not yet receiving the email

Comment: I don't understand, that is just the answer from some question here in stackoverflow.

Comment: `echo mail(); //I use this to see the error` is actually calling the mail function again and not outputting the result of `mail($targetEmail, $subject, $message);`. Check my answer.

Comment: Yes, it returns true, but I'm not receiving the email

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
<?php
$targetEmail = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Sending e-mails from PHP is fun!';
$message = 'Do you agree?';

$mail = mail($targetEmail, $subject, $message);
echo $mail;
```

Comment: I think this is just the same as to what I've posted

Comment: @Noobster, No, I assigned to the variable $mail the status of the sent mail (true or false). then echoed it.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `echo mail();` it is calling the function `mail()` again but you are not passing any variables to it. Try:

```
$mail = mail($targetEmail, $subject, $message);
echo $mail;
```

However, according to the mail() [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php); the function accepts:
`bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )`

But you have to set-up the sender email in the $additional_headers variable to be able to send the email. Try this:

```
$targetEmail = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Sending e-mails from PHP is fun!';
$message = 'Do you agree?';
$headers = "From: your-email@example.com" . "\r\n" .
    "CC: somebodyelse@example.com";

$mail = mail($targetEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo $mail;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
 <?php
    $to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Sending e-mails from PHP is fun!';
    $message = 'Do you agree?';
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    if(mail($to, $subject, $message ,$headers)){
        echo "successfully  mailed";
    }
    else{
        echo "Failure";
    }

    ?>
```

It works fine..!